# Need of billing account in Google Speech API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-speech-api

I am trying to develop an application based on Google Speech API. Basically the API is used to get the transcripts of some wav files which are used in my application. The issue is while making API calls I am getting an error

" has billing disabled. Please enable it.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED*".

Is it because I did some configuration wrong or do I need to enable billing even if my application is not used for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to enable billing if you want to use the Google Speech API, regardless of whether your project is commercial or not. You will get a certain amount of time that you can use free each month, but above that you have to pay for the service. You can find out more about pricing here: https://cloud.google.com/speech/pricing